# How can I fix this FS00003 error?

Tags: f#

This is my code:

```
module RTX

open System
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let input = "Line 1: Num allocs:3 New:2 Delete:1
Line 2: Num allocs:3 New:2 Delete:1
Line 3: Num allocs:3 New:2 Delete:1"

type AllocResult = { lineNo:string; numAllocs:string; news:string; frees:string }

let matches = Regex.Matches(input,@"Line (\d+): Num allocs:(\d+) New:(\d+) Delete:(\d+)",RegexOptions.Singleline)
let matchCollection = [ for m in matches do if m.Success then yield [for l in m.Groups -> l.Value]]
let allocCreator (e: string list) = { lineNo = e.[0]; numAllocs = e.[1]; news = e.[2]; frees = e.[3] }
let wfirst = List.map allocCreator List.map List.tail matchCollection

List.iter (fun e -> printfn "%s\n") wfirst
//List.iter (printfn "%s\n") matchCollection
Console.ReadLine()
```

The error I receive is: `This value is not a function and cannot be applied (FS0003)`, and it appears at the `List.map allocCreator` part. Basically, I want to remove the string that matched from the Match, and keep only the captures in a record.

EDIT: I will try to explain a little more what I wanted to achieve.The Match result will be something like this:

```
[ "Line 1: Num allocs:3 New:2 Delete:1"; "1"; "3"; "2"; "1"; ]
```

By using 
`let matchCollection = [ for m in matches do if m.Success then yield [for l in m.Groups -> l.Value]]` I was trying to get a list of lists ,something like this:

```
[["Line 1: Num allocs:3 New:2 Delete:1"; "1"; "3"; "2"; "1"; ];["Line 2: Num allocs:3 New:2 Delete:1";"2"; "3"; "2"; "1"; ]; ["Line 3: Num allocs:3 New:2 Delete:1";"3"; "3"; "2"; "1"]]
```

By using `List.map List.tail matchCollection`, I was trying to get from the above list, to this:

```
[["1"; "3"; "2"; "1"; ];["2"; "3"; "2"; "1"; ]; [;"3"; "3"; "2"; "1"]]
```

And by using `List.map allocCreator` I was trying to turn the above list into a list of records. I'm kinda new at F# and I probably my logic is wrong, but I don't understand why/where.

EDIT 2: It seems like a precedence issue. If I do this:

```
let wfirst = List.map allocCreator (List.map List.tail matchCollection);;
```

Then I get what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let wfirst = List.map allocCreator <| List.map List.tail matchCollection
List.iter (printfn "%A\n") wfirst
```

Comment: can you please explain why your version works and mine doesn't? Isn't this how the compiler sees the expression:`List.map(allocCreator, List.map(List.tail,matchCollection))`?

Comment: The compiler sees it as:  `(List.map allocCreator List.map) (List.tail matchCollection)` because function application associates to the left.

Comment: List.map : (('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list) is func -> arg -> result becouse List.map func1 List.map something, (List.map func1 List.map) part should be 'b list, ('b list) something is attempting to execute ,So compiler say "This value('b list) is not a function and cannot be applied", So you need to change the order of execution by use ().

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with that line, but lets look at the types to try and figure it out

first

```
List.map allocCreater
```

this is already incorrect, the first argument to map needs to have type `'a -> 'b` but you have given a list

```
List.map List.tail matchCollection
```

this is a `string list list`

I have no idea what you are actually trying to get at here, but you seem to be short a function or have too many lists